# Putting existing sqlite database into memory using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I recently became aware of the sqlalchemy `raw_connections()` method which gives you the ability to use the DBAPI for the given relational db. I was hoping I could use this method to load an existing database into memory like so:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
connection = engine.raw_connection()
src = sqlite3.connect("Name of existing db")
src.backup(connection)
```

Unfortuntaley the object returned by `raw_connection()` is a `_ConnectionFairy` object and the following error occurs: `TypeError: backup() argument 1 must be sqlite3.Connection, not _ConnectionFairy`

Does anyone know a work around this or possibly a working method of what I am trying to do?

Comment: You can access the actual DB-API connection through the raw connection using its `connection` attribute.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thank you!